# how to add value or text to other level right above element using python

Tags: python, xml

I got a question.
how do i add or insert attribute value at the end of nodes in other element?
Actually, i know how to do it but it's not my problem.
I want to add each value of `LinkResourceURI` to the element `Content` located above `Link` element.

please see example as following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Root>
    <Story>
        <XMLElement>
            <ParagraphStyleRange>
                <XMLElement>
                    <CharacterStyleRange>
                        <Content>BBBBBBBBBB </Content>
                        <Rectangle>
                            <PDF>
                                <Link LinkResourceURI="file:C:/test/111.ai"/>
                            </PDF>
                        </Rectangle>
                        <Rectangle>
                            <PDF>
                                <Link LinkResourceURI="file:C:/test/222.ai"/>
                            </PDF>
                        </Rectangle>
                        <Content>CCCCCCCCCC </Content>
                        <Rectangle>
                            <PDF>
                                <Link LinkResourceURI="file:C:/test/333.ai"/>
                            </PDF>
                        </Rectangle>
                    </CharacterStyleRange>
                    <CharacterStyleRange>
                        <Content>DDDDDDDDDD</Content>
                        <Rectangle>
                            <PDF>
                                <Link LinkResourceURI="file:C:/test/444.ai"/>
                            </PDF>
                        </Rectangle>
                    </CharacterStyleRange>
                </XMLElement>
            </ParagraphStyleRange>
        </XMLElement>
    </Story>
</Root>
```

and this is what i'm trying to code.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("c:\\TEST\\XML_data.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

for Story in root.findall('Story'):
    for XMLElement in Story.findall('XMLElement'):
        for ParagraphStyleRange in XMLElement.findall('ParagraphStyleRange'):
            for XMLElement_1 in ParagraphStyleRange.findall('XMLElement'):
                for CharacterStyleRange in XMLElement_1.findall('CharacterStyleRange'):
                    for Rectangle in CharacterStyleRange.findall('Rectangle'):
                        for PDF in Rectangle.findall('PDF'):
                            for Link in PDF.findall('Link'):
                                Link_URL = Link.get('LinkResourceURI')
                                Link_count = len(PDF.findall('Link'))
                                print(Link_count)
                                if int(Link_count) >= 1 :
                                    for CharacterStyleRange in XMLElement_1.findall('CharacterStyleRange'):
                                        for Content in CharacterStyleRange.findall('Content'):
                                        Content.text = str(Content.text)+ '-----' + Link_URL + '-----'
                                else :
                                 pass                                                


tree.write('C:\\test\\datafiles\\Link_test_result.xml')
```

---

This result is what i need.

```
<Story>
    <XMLElement>
        <ParagraphStyleRange>
            <XMLElement>
                <CharacterStyleRange>
                    <Content>BBBBBBBBBB C:/test/11l.aiC:/test/222.ai</Content>
                    <Rectangle>
                        <PDF>
                            <Link LinkResourceURI="file:C:/test/111.ai"/>
                        </PDF>
                    </Rectangle>
                    <Rectangle>
                        <PDF>
                            <Link LinkResourceURI="file:C:/test/222.ai"/>
                        </PDF>
                    </Rectangle>
                    <Content>CCCCCCCCCC file:C:/test/333.ai</Content>
                    <Rectangle>
                        <PDF>
                            <Link LinkResourceURI="file:C:/test/333.ai"/>
                        </PDF>
                    </Rectangle>
                </CharacterStyleRange>
                <CharacterStyleRange>
                    <Content>DDDDDDDDDDfile:C:/test/444.ai</Content>
                    <Rectangle>
                        <PDF>
                            <Link LinkResourceURI="file:C:/test/444.ai"/>
                        </PDF>
                    </Rectangle>
                </CharacterStyleRange>
            </XMLElement>
        </ParagraphStyleRange>
    </XMLElement>
</Story>
```

There is no error, but this isn't what i want. 
it inserts all values into all `Content` node.

Would you advise for me ?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear to me in explaining what you actually want to achieve. Please edit your question and add the XML you would like to get because I can't work that out from what you have written. Do you want to copy the LinkURI attribute content into a LinkURI attribute on the Content tag? What should happen when there is more than one tag with a LinkURI attribute below a Content tag?

Comment: And update your code/output because when I run what is in your question it doesn't find the Story elements so doesn't do anything and when I fix that I get different output in the Content tags from what you show - for example there are ------ around what is added when I run your code, that you don't show in the question.

Comment: Oh I think I see your problem - you want to insert the LinkURI attribute values into the Content tag that precedes them. That's horrible. If you can restructure the XML I'd suggest putting the Rectangle tags inside the Content tag they relate to.

Comment: Barny,  you understand what i mean. thanks. yes it's too hard to solve for me cause the rectangle tag is same level with Content tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem is that the XML is IMO not very well structured and the sequence of tags matters for what you want to do, which is: copy the LinkURI attribute value and append to the text of the preceding Content tag.

One way to do this (there may be other ways) is to iterate over the children of the CharacterStyleRange tag - because this keeps the sequence of child tags - then remember the most recent Content tag and append the LinkURI attribute content to the text of that tag.

Also, you can shorten/simplify your access into the nested tags using XPath in findall().

Also, I couldn't get your code to work because the initial `for Story in root.findall('Story'):` didn't return anything.

Anyway, this code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("XML_data.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

for CharacterStyleRange in root.findall('.//CharacterStyleRange'):
    # iterate through the children so we can work with the sequence of Content and Rectangle tags
    for child in CharacterStyleRange:
        if child.tag == 'Content':
            # remember the preceding content tag
            thecontent = child
        elif child.tag == 'Rectangle':                    
            for Link in child.findall('.//Link'):
                Link_URL = Link.get('LinkResourceURI')
                # append the attribute value to the preceding content tag
                thecontent.text += '-----' + Link_URL + '-----'

tree.write('Link_test_result.xml')
```

Produces this output:

```
<Story>
    <XMLElement>
        <ParagraphStyleRange>
            <XMLElement>
                <CharacterStyleRange>
                    <Content>BBBBBBBBBB -----file:C:/test/111.ai----------file:C:/test/222.ai-----</Content>
                    <Rectangle>
                        <PDF>
                            <Link LinkResourceURI="file:C:/test/111.ai" />
                        </PDF>
                    </Rectangle>
                    <Rectangle>
                        <PDF>
                            <Link LinkResourceURI="file:C:/test/222.ai" />
                        </PDF>
                    </Rectangle>
                    <Content>CCCCCCCCCC -----file:C:/test/333.ai-----</Content>
                    <Rectangle>
                        <PDF>
                            <Link LinkResourceURI="file:C:/test/333.ai" />
                        </PDF>
                    </Rectangle>
                </CharacterStyleRange>
                <CharacterStyleRange>
                    <Content>DDDDDDDDDD-----file:C:/test/444.ai-----</Content>
                    <Rectangle>
                        <PDF>
                            <Link LinkResourceURI="file:C:/test/444.ai" />
                        </PDF>
                    </Rectangle>
                </CharacterStyleRange>
            </XMLElement>
        </ParagraphStyleRange>
    </XMLElement>
</Story>
```

Comment: Barny!! This is great for real!! I didn't come up with using .tag method for this. What a genius you are! i learned onething today from you. Appreciate.

Comment: :-) You're new around here - if I've answered your question then please consider accepting and upvoting my answer.

Comment: I suggest you go through the ElementTree tutorial in the Python docs - you'll find all sorts of interesting things.

Comment: Okay, I've been going through ElementTree tutorial but it's so hard for novice and foreigner..everything is in english. anyhow i accepted your answer... and upvoting? what is it.would you let me know how to do it ?

Comment: Upvote (if you hven’t already) by clicking the up-arrow to the left of the answer above the count of votes.